# Best approach to merge three distinct TSQL select statments

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to return one tsql statement, that contains four fields, from three separate, unrelated tables.

One table contains a list of objects, say fruits, and for each fruit, I want a sell buy date and best before date.

First statement would therefore look something like:

```
select fruit from fruit table -- this returns multiple rows
```

Second statement would look something like:

```
select sellbuyDate from sellTable -- this returns a single row
```

and the third would look something like:

```
select bestbefore from bestTable -- this returns a single row
```

Don't get to hung up on the table names. I'm working on a legacy system, that we cant change, so need to combine the three table into one.

The underlining table needs to have all the fields returned in a single row, with the second and third results applied to the first statement.

Apples | 12-12-2008 | 12-12-2009

Pears  | 12-12-2008 | 12-12-2009

I've implemented the following temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Fruits
( 
Fruit VARCHAR(100),
SellBuyDate DATETIME,
BestBefore DATETIME
) 
INSERT INTO #Fruits
   SELECT Fruit from fruit
INSERT INTO #Fruits
  SELECT sellbuyDate from sellTable
INSERT INTO #Fruits
  SELECT bestbefore from bestable
SELECT * from #Fruits
```

This throws an error, because each insert doesn't contain the three fields specified.

any other suggestions would be well received.

Comment: well i guess you will need some kind of a join, what other columns do the tables have?

Comment: Hi cproinger - they are all standalone tables, no link between that at all.

Comment: Not sure why the mark down!!!

Comment: How do you know which sellbuyDate or bestbefore applies to which fruit?  If there's no link it'll just be a cross join and you'll get all the rows from all three tables.

Comment: Its doesn't matter - Michael - they have to be applied to all instances of Fruit.

Comment: Then just do a cross join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select them all together by doing a `CROSS JOIN` by not specifying any join criteria between the three tables as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE fruit ( fruit_name VARCHAR(30) );

CREATE TABLE sellTable ( sellByDate DATETIME );

CREATE TABLE bestTable ( bestBefore DATETIME );

CREATE TABLE allFruits
(
    fruit_name VARCHAR(30),
    sellByDate DATETIME,
    bestBefore DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO fruit (fruit_name)
VALUES ('apple'), ('pear');

INSERT INTO sellTable(sellByDate)
VALUES ('12/05/2012');

INSERT INTO bestTable(bestBefore)
VALUES ('12/12/2012');

INSERT INTO allFruits (fruit_name, bestBefore, sellByDate)
SELECT f.fruit_name, b.bestBefore, s.sellByDate
FROM fruit f, bestTable b, sellTable s;

SELECT *
FROM allFruits;
```

Comment: @CSharpNewBee The only risk here is that if SellTable or BestTable EVER have more than 1 row, your results will be skewed.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you are looking for this answer, although your question could be a little clearer on what that would accomplish

```
INSERT INTO #Fruits(fruit)
   SELECT Fruit from fruit
INSERT INTO #Fruits(sellbuyDate)
  SELECT sellbuyDate from sellTable
INSERT INTO #Fruits(bestbefore)
  SELECT bestbefore from bestable
SELECT * from #Fruits
```

the other possible solution is

```
insert into #Fruits
select Fruit, sellbuyDate, bestbefore from fruit
        cross join sellTable
        cross join bestable
```

Comment: I think the cross join is the most straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need this.

```
SELECT FRUIT,
       (SELECT SELLBUYDATE FROM SELLTABLE) AS SELLBUYDATE,
       (SELECT BESTBEFORE FROM BESTTABLE) AS BESTBEFORE
FROM FRUIT
```

or

```
SELECT FRUIT.FRUIT
     , SELLTABLE.SELLBUYDATE
     , BESTTABLE.BESTBEFORE 
FROM FRUIT
INNER JOIN SELLTABLE ON 1=1
INNER JOIN BESTTABLE ON 1=1
```

Comment: Reasonable,but the multiple times the select is executed for each fruit seems like alot of overhead.  Cross join would likely be better.

Comment: we can also use inner join like SELLBUYDATE ON 1=1 Right?

Comment: Yes, but this just confuses the issue, why obfuscate the cross join?

Answer (score -1):

Without the schema of the 3 tables. I would guess its one of the following.

```
CREATE TABLE #Fruits
( 
Fruit VARCHAR(100),
SellBuyDate DATETIME,
BestBefore DATETIME
) 
INSERT INTO #Fruits(Fruit,SellBuyDate,BestBefore)
Select Fruit, Sellbuydate,bestbefore
from fruit,selltable,bestable
```

Or if your tables are set up properly

```
INSERT INTO #Fruits(Fruit,SellBuyDate,BestBefore)
Select Fruit, Sellbuydate,bestbefore
from fruit f
inner join selltable s
on f.pkey = s.fkey
inner join bestable b
on f.pkey = b.fkey
```

Comment: "from three separate, unrelated tables" they're not related.